# memcache on yii blog architecture

Tags: php, architecture, yii, memcached, blogs

I've recently added a blog to my php yii website that is a heavily modified version of the yii blog demo.  My blog uses active record, which unfortunately uses roughly 20 database calls to display a post.  I'd like to speed this up with memcache.  I'd like to cache as much of the content as I can in memory to get rid of that insane number of db calls.  I've already enabled the schema caching, which cuts the number of calls down to more like 12 or 13, but that's still too many.

While load testing my blog, I discovered that under heavy load my cpu is the limiting factor.  I still have plenty of ram.  So I'm hoping that putting some of that extra ram to use will cut down the load on my cpu.  That's where memcache comes in.  The problem is how to architect it.

I've figured out how to cache a single post with comments and tags, that's not terribly difficult.  What I'm struggling with is how to cache the index pages, which have a number of posts on each one.  Page 1 would have 5 posts, page 2 would have 5 posts, etc.  I'm making the database call like this:

```
           $criteria=new CDbCriteria(array(
                    'condition'=>'status='.Post::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
                    'order'=>'create_time DESC',
                    'with'=>'commentCount',
            ));
            if(!is_null($tag))
                    $criteria->addSearchCondition('tags', $tag);

            $dataProvider=new ActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
                    'pagination'=>array(
                            'pageVar'=>'page',
                            'pageSize'=>5,
                    ),
                    'criteria'=>$criteria,
            ));

            $this->render('index',array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
```

I was originally thinking I could just cache the resulting $dataProvider with the query string as the key.  Something I could get with:

```
echo http_build_query($criteria->toArray());
```

I would have to append the page number to that key, but that's easy.  However, doing it this way would mean I would need to have a separate dataProvider cached for every page and every tag, which would be a nightmare to update if I were to update the tags or add a new post.

I'm sure one of you brilliant people could give me some suggestions.  I'm at a loss of how to architect this.

Comment: Why not just cache the whole page?

Comment: That's what I'm saying though.  If I were to just catch each page, if I were to create a new post I would then have to invalidate all the index pages in my cache as well as any pages associated with posts tagged the same.

Comment: I don't think invalidating the cache is that big a deal. If you now have 20 DB calls and a lot of PHP code execution *every pageload*, you'll now have it every time you have a new post or a new tag. You're gaining a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion caching the whole page or fragments of the page is the way to go.

For caching the whole page ( or action) , yii provides [`COutputCache`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/COutputCache). And for fragment caching there is [`CController::beginCache()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#beginCache) and [`CController::endCache()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#endCache). For more info refer the documentation for [page caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.page#output-caching) and [fragment caching](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment)

**About Invalidating the cache on content change**

From yii documentation

> Besides expiration setting, cached data may also be invalidated
>   according to some dependency changes. For example, if we are caching
>   the content of some file and the file is changed, we should invalidate
>   the cached copy and read the latest content from the file instead of
>   the cache.

Dependency can be specified by the instance of [`CCacheDependency`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCacheDependency) or its child class. For your specific need you may use the [`CDbCacheDependency`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency) with sql like

```
SELECT `update_time` from post where `id`=:id
```

for caching a page of a specific post entry.

For other available dependency classes see the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency)

Comment: But using CDbCacheDependency means that before every cache hit, a query is ran to make sure the cache entry is valid.  So all I'm doing if I use that specific dependency is exchanging one expensive sql query for a less expensive one, right?  Because I can see the the dependency queries going now instead.  I still have a number of queries, just they are all cheap ones.  Maybe I would be better off not using dependencies, just invalidating the cache entry myself.  I would end up saving a number of queries that way I bet.  I'll run some benchmarks and see.

Comment: Its not mandatory that you use CDbCacheDependency. You can use other dependancies . For example store the update timestamp of a post in a file and you can use CFileCacheDependency.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  After some benchmarks, it doesn't look like using query caching with dependencies really made my blog much faster.  It's not like my queries are really expensive, it's just there's a lot of them.  Using dependencies exchanges one query for another, even with other types of dependencies.  I'm gonna look into using yii's implementation of get and set and invalidating cache entries by hand.  Hopefully that will speed things up.